# Is using a circuit breaker approach to handling http 429 responses too much of an overkill

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, polly, circuit-breaker

I have a service that I call. Lets call that `LookupService`. I have the following line of code in my client application call that service

```
var resp= serviceClient.Lookup(payLoad);
```

Now the `LookupService` has been configured by the owners of that service to not allow more than 5 concurrent service calls per client. Anymore than that and they will return HTTP 429.

I am thinking of injecting this one call to a checking method just before the call to the `Lookup` method. Something to the effect of:

```
ICircuitBreaker cb = CircuitBreakerFactory.GetInstance(); //return a retry instance
cb.Break();
var resp= serviceClient.Lookup(payLoad);
```

As of right now I want to only pause and retry if the max number of concurrent calls has been hit or if service returns http code 429. I will register to an internal static variable just before each call to the Lookup method and deregister the call when the service has returned.
But later on, I will want to implement another class that provides an alternate path of action or uses a fallback service. I am aware there is a retry pattern, but I feel registering each call and keeping track of calls being made to compare against the total allowed calls that the service will allow since I already know that in advance will help me preemptively break the circuit when I know it is going to fail.

Thoughts on this pattern. Workable, perfect, overkill?

Comment: Let me know which board I can post this question to, if this is not the correct board for it.

Comment: If the scenario of too many calls currently occurs or you foresee it will occur in the near future then a circuit breaker is not an overkill. Otherwise if you want to add it just in case it will be needed sometime in the future it might be an overkill, though if time spent to add it is not a concern then add it anyway is a good chance to experiment

Comment: How are you actually doing the HTTP messaging? If possible, you get access to the `ServicePoint` or morally equivalent object that all connections to that server are using and *apply a connection limit* (e.g. for `HttpClient` you can manually construct a `HttpClientHandler` and set its `MaxConnectionsPerServer` property)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the question that you have raised I can see some confusion around different resilient strategies. Let me try to make them clear.

There are **consumer-side** (*reactive*) and **producer-side** (*proactive*) patterns / techniques / strategies. The former ones usually react on a *fault* and the later ones try to prevent the error / fault.

Well-known consumer-side patterns: **timeout**, **retry** and **circuit breaker**.
Well-known producer-side patterns: **rate limiting**, **load shedding,** **back pressure** and **bulkhead**.

In order to deliver reliable solutions usually is not enough to apply patterns only on one side. In other words, only smart clients can react on servers' **back off** requests.

---

According to my understanding you want to limit the concurrent requests from the same machine. Let examine the producer- and consumer-side one-by-one:

1) Producer-side
The rate limiting pattern (also known as **throttling**) is usually used to prevent request flooding. You can define several pairs of **duration** and **threshold** to describe the acceptable load from a given machine:

- 5 requests / min
- 100 requests / hour
- 1000 requests / day

If the user exceeds any of thresholds then you can impose some sort of **penalty**. Usually this is done by *rejecting* the requests with `403`. When the duration expired then the counter is set back to zero and the service receives requests again from the client.

There are some implementations where the `429` (Too many requests) status code is used instead of `403`. This is also correct, but it is a combination of two patterns. The **back pressure** is the other pattern. This technique can be used to tell gently to the clients that "“I’m currently busy, please come back later". Here you have the ability to define when the client should come back by specifying the `Retry-After` header. This can be either an *absolute* or a *relative* datetime:

- absolute, for example: Wed, 29 Apr 2020 08:11:00 GMT
- relative, for example: 120 seconds

2) Consumer-side
On the client side you can use the combination of circuit breaker and retry to achieve the  required resilient solution.

The circuit breaker can be used to prevent to flood the temporary inaccessible downstream system. In our case this means whenever the rate limiting exposes the penalty then the breaker can go from **Closed** to **Open** state. This will prevent the consumer to send requests to the downstream system and instead it fails immediately on the client side.

The Retry-After header can be used to set the state from **Open** to **Half-Open**. So, when the exposed penalty elapsed then the breaker allow to the consumer to make new requests.

In order to avoid loosing any requests, we can apply the retry logic. The retry logic should be aware of the circuit breaker. So, it tries to send a request and if the concurrent requests count is under the threshold then nothing special happens. If the threshold is exceeded then the breaker is Open, so the request will fail immediately and a new attempt is required a bit later. The retry itself can also take advantage of the `Retry-After` header as well to specify the delay between the initial call and the next attempt.

---

Please visit the [Polly project](http://www.thepollyproject.org/), where you can find most of these techniques are implemented for .NET developers. I hope this helped you a bit.